# Определение координат окна

Tags: winapi, vb.net, visual-basic

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно найти координаты окна процесса.

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpRect As RECT) As Long

    Public Structure RECT
        Public Left As Long
        Public Top As Long
        Public Right As Long
        Public Bottom As Long
    End Structure

    Public one As RECT

    Sub Main()
        Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        With process.StartInfo
            .FileName = "calc.exe"
            .Arguments = ""
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            .CreateNoWindow = False
        End With
        process.Start()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        GetWindowRect(process.Handle, one)
        MsgBox(one.Left)
        MsgBox(one.Top)
    End Sub
```

Программа выводит нули. Подскажите пожалуйста , В чём может быть ошибка ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Читайте про [`Process.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx)
2. У функций API необходимо проверять возращаемое значение, расширенная информация доступна через функцию `GetLastError`